Which property for org.digidoc4j.Configuration class hold the OCSP responder URL?
Which property for org.digidoc4j.Configuration class hold the OCSP responder URL? I want to programmatically set the OCSP responder URL via org.digidoc4j.Configuration class. Also, let me know if there is any other way to set the OCSP Resolver URL using digidoc4j:5.0.0 library.

I have written the below code by using setOcspSource(), but somehow it is not hitting the OCSP Responder that I set here. I was looking for a method like setOcspResponderURL() or setOcspUrl(), however, not found any such method in org.digidoc4j.Configuration class for digidoc4j:5.0.0 library.
org.digidoc4j.Configuration conf = org.digidoc4j.Configuration.of(mode);
conf.setOcspSource("http://myocspresponder.com");


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
